# What and why is there a format key in the header params hash when redirected, but not when rendered?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, http-headers

I have a Controller#action which when redirected_to has a url appended with '.1' and `params["format"=>'1']` in the header params. When I hit the same Controller#action without a redirect, e.g. from a `link_to` the url is not appended with this '.1' variable and neither does the params hash contain a `format` variable.

Why does this variable appear when the action is hit in one way an not the other and what is this variable's purpose? Code as below:

routes/rb;

```
root 'routes#root'
```

RoutesController.rb:

```
class RoutesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def root
    if current_user.company.present? 
      redirect_to new_company_quote_path(current_user, current_user.company) #, status '301'
    else
      redirect_to new_company_path(current_user) #, status '301'
    end
  end
end
```

When the conditional branch redirects_to `new_company_quote_path` the url is appended with a '.1', like this; `http://localhost:3000/companies/1/quotes/new.1`, with params like;

`<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"quotes", "action"=>"new", "company_id"=>"1", "format"=>"1"} permitted: false>`.

When the conditional branch redirects_to `new_company_path` the url is appended with a '.2', like this; `http://localhost:3000/companies/new.2`, with params like;

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"companies", "action"=>"new", "format"=>"2"} permitted: false>
```

Comment: The `.1` is a format suffix (think web-pages ending with `.html` or `.php`). My guess would be that somewhere somehow rails is expecting to receive the format and receiving the resource id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 2 routes in question should likely be:

```
new_company_quote_path(current_user.company)
new_company_path
```

and since extra parameters are being passed, it's believing those are for the `:format` key and calling `to_param` on them. Trying to find some documentation on the generated route helpers to verify this is what would be happening, but having no luck, so this is more of a "strong suspicion" than verified fact. Though at least part of this can be verified [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers)

> ```
> photos_path returns /photos
> new_photo_path returns /photos/new
> edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
> photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
> ```

So the `new` path doesn't take an `:id` (and thus doesn't need any parameters) and then the `new_company_quote_path` sounds nested so would take a single parameter (of company)

Comment: Of course @simple-lime, thank you, you were exactly right , all corrected now.